# How to collapse an accordion when it loses focus?

Tags: jquery-ui, accordion

I am using the accordion that is part of the jquery-ui framework. I want the accordion to collapse completely when the user clicks on another part of the screen.

I have tried to attach a blur event to the accordion container but this never seems to fire an unexpected times.

Here is an example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UEg9a/6/)

As you can see, the blur event is fired when an accordion section is closed and at no other time. I want an event to fire only when an open accordion section loses focus.

I have also tried attaching a blur event to the accordion sections but this never seems to fire. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/V889R/8/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this successfully using the [events outside plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-outside-events-plugin/). I think this is quite a heavy solution so if anybody has a better one, that would be great.

Instead of using a blur event, just use a 'clickoutside' event binded to the container element:

```
$('.container').bind('clickoutside', function() {
  $(this).accordion("activate", false);
});
```

This won't work if the user tabs outside the element or otherwise loses focus without clicking but it was sufficient for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it's not as easy as you might think. See this for a partial solution:

```
function activate() {

    $('.container').accordion("destroy");

    $('.container').accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        active: false
    });

}

activate();

$('.container h3').live( 'blur', function() {
    $(".container").accordion('activate', false);
    activate(); // this should be delayed until the elements are closed
});
```

It destroys and reactivates the accordion, the only solution I found right now.

It works, but the closing animation does not. Maybe with a little bit trying you can get it to work properly (see the hint in the code).

EDIT:

note I removed the `<a>`-tags, so the headers look like this:

```
    <h3>Example</h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

my second try, without a plugin (but still somewhat heavy):
Simply compares mouse position with container's dimensions.

---

EDIT: Now with focus, too.

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/btPeP/1/)

EDIT 2: Unfortunately a little but buggy, collapsed items sometimes do not open again... you have to click a second time outside the container. Don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [JQuery's `mouseleave` event](https://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)

From the documentation:

> The mouseleave JavaScript event is proprietary to Internet Explorer.
>   Because of the event's general utility, jQuery simulates this event so
>   that it can be used regardless of browser. This event is sent to an
>   element when the mouse pointer leaves the element. Any HTML element
>   can receive this event.

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/user2314737/8rtt1eLt/show/)

HTML

```
<div id="outside"></div>

<div id="accordion">
  <div>Panel 0</div>
  <div>Content 0</div>
  <div>Panel 1</div>
  <div>Content 1</div>
  <div>Panel2</div>
  <div>Content 2</div>
```

JS

```
  $('#accordion').accordion({
    heightStyle: "content",
    collapsible: true,
    active: false
  });

  $('#accordion').on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).accordion("activate", false);
  });
```